# Keyboard overlaps Entry in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

There are `ListView`, `Entry` and `Button` inside `ContentPage`, something like this:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
   <ListView>
   ...
   ...
   </ListView>

   <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Entry ... />
      <Button ... />
   </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

When I focus that `Entry`, a keyboard overlaps `Entry` and `Button`.
I know, there is a solution: putting elements inside `ScrollView`, but this solution makes huge problems with scrolling `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. What should I do, to make it work properly?

Comment: What do you want to achieve using this? can u share the UI?

Comment: Here is a screenshot https://imgur.com/hDGw97w

Comment: This screenshot with ScrollView added, and the keyboard doesn't overlap Entry and Button, but ListView scrolling conflicts with ScrollView scrolling

Comment: Adding Entry and Button into ListView.Footer is not an option, because they shouldn't move while scrolling and their position should be absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do not mix `ListView` and `ScrollView` in same view, result will not be ok!

Instead I suggest you to take a look at this repository **Xamarin.Forms.Plugins - KeyboardOverlap** [here](https://github.com/paulpatarinski/Xamarin.Forms.Plugins/tree/master/KeyboardOverlap).

The main goal of this repository is resolve that issue of overlapping the entries with keyboard on iOS, There is also a nuget package which you can use, you can find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.KeyboardOverlap/).

But also it is fully open-source... so you can take a look at code implementation and custom renderer and tweak more if you ever need.

Wish you good luck with coding!

Comment: It seems this plugin doesn't work: I included it to iOS project, added KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init() after Xamarin.Forms.Init(); 
And when I focus Entry, it doesn't move up

Comment: Try to add this custom renderer manually and see what will happend.

Comment: Thanks, I've figured out. Package didn't work because I already had a custom renderer for ContentPage.

Comment: Nice, happy to hear that, and also thank you for accepting the answer. :)

Comment: @SgtMaddonut Included keyboard overlap nuget in ios project and added init lines, but when focus entry still keyboard hiding the entry. I am not using any customerender in contentpages, please help me guys?

Comment: For Android adding this in MainActivity worked 
[Activity( MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | 
    | ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden, WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)]

Comment: For MAUI iOS this one worked https://github.com/massijay/iOSMauiScrollUpOnKeyboardShow/blob/main/Controls/FixedScrollView.cs